# Display MySQL query in a HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

The following code displays table on the form but I need to format the table in a specific fashion.
The desired output is displayed in image. So I need to manipulate the query someway where I can convert Sprinkler_ID columns to 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. So, if there is no Sprinkler_ID let say "2" in our original table then the desired table should print "no" in the "2" field otherwise YES.
[image]

```
<?php
include('config.php');
echo "<h4>Current Schedules</h4>";
echo "<table border=2 >"; 
echo "<tr>"; 

echo "<td><b>Sprinkler_Id</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Schedule_Id</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Starttime</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Stoptime</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Monday</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Tuesday</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Wednesday</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Thursday</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Friday</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Saturday</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Sunday</b></td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 

$sql = "SELECT daystime.*, Sprinkler_ID FROM daystime, scheduler WHERE daystime.id = scheduler.DaysTime_ID ORDER BY Sprinkler_ID, daystime.id";
$results=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
$id = $row['id']; 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['Sprinkler_ID']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['id']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['starttime']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['stoptime']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['mon']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['tue']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['wed']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['thu']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['fri']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['sat']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['sun']) . "</td>";  
echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 

?>
```

[image: current results]

Comment: I'm not sure I understood that well, what are the existing values for `Sprinkler_ID`?

Comment: so the values stored in the database are 1...8. but the query will not necessary return all the values. so when a SPKr_ID is not fetched by the query it means that sprinkler is not yet assigned and so its value for that Schedule (id,start,stop,days of week) will be no otherwise yes

Comment: So in cases where the value doesn't exist, does it show `null` or empty?

Comment: thats why I showed in the image what I require

Comment: it can show "no" if they are not there.

Comment: What are the columns that are going to be 1-8? Which columns do they relate to? Try and explain the situation a bit better, probably with an OP edit

Comment: so i added a new image that shows my current query results, so I need to modify the Sprinkler_ID that I fetch in such a way that I get that is displayed in image at the very top

Comment: @PrerakDiwan After a lot of staring into the images I think I understood what you need, try my updated code and let me know that works for you.

Comment: can u please add your lines to my code so I don't make errors as adding stuff here and there are giving me a lot of errors. help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first custom create the 1-8 columns not present so for that do:

```
//...continued from code
echo "<td><b>Saturday</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Sunday</b></td>"; 
for($i=1;$i<=8;$i++){
echo "<td><b>".$i."</b></td>"; 
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Then, we use the following:

```
$ids=array();
#we'll first save all the ids into an array
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    $ids[$row['id']][]=$row['Sprinkler_ID'];
}
$listed=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    $id = $row['id'];

    if(!in_array($id,$listed)){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['id']) . "</td>";
      //...all your other rows


      for($i=1;$i<=8;$i++){
        if(in_array($i,$ids[$id])){
            echo "<td valign='top'>yes</td>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<td valign='top'>no</td>";
        }
      }


      echo "</tr>";
      $listed[]=$id;

    }
}
```

The logic is, we first group the repeating `Sprinkler_id` by the `id` as:

```
    19 => 
       [0] => 4,
       [1] => 5, 

    20 => 
       [0] => 5,

    21 => 
       [0] => 4,
       [1] => 6
```

Then while it's looping through the `id` we make sure that row is printed only once using `$listed[]` array. As for the 'yes' and 'no', we use the previously grouped array to check if the `sprinkler_id` for that `id` exists. If it does, it's a 'yes' else 'no'.

Comment: so I am not sure everybody is getting this or not? so if you see the query results above there is no spr7 or 8 . But there has to be a column created for them but their values will be no for Schedule_ID records? Am I making sense??

Comment: @PrerakDiwan Ah, missed that, ok another thing is, the Sprinkler_ID `5` has both id `19`(repeating) and `20`(not repeating). So is it still a _yes_?

Comment: so think it like our main ID for the table is id or Schedule_ID. this specific thing is required so the table size does not increase if I have all the Schedule ID assigned to say Spkr 1,2,3 so 24 records which is not feasible to display on the table.

Comment: @PrerakDiwan This is getting more complicated, I presume the first image is not the final output, could you please make an image of the _final_ output table to make things clear?

Comment: updated so now compare the two tables the top one is desired and the bottom one is I have

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger

Comment: @PrerakDiwan Try the above and let me know if any errors.

Comment: then why do we need Sprinkler Id here if(!in_array($id,$listed)){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['Sprinkler_ID']) . "</td>";

Comment: @PrerakDiwan Yea, that shouldn't be there. You can remove it from the header and row.

Comment: let me try this I will get back to u soon

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger  it does not print any row besides the table header so no records

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52167/discussion-between-i-can-has-cheezburger-and-prerak-diwan)

Comment: this answer works for me thanks @I Can Has Cheezburger

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this maintain a static array  for Sprinkle Ids in your php file and then check if value coming from Db exists in this array

```
    <?php
    include('config.php');
     $sprinkleIds = range(1,8);
    echo "<h4>Current Schedules</h4>";
    echo "<table border=2 >"; 
    echo "<tr>"; 

    echo "<td><b>Sprinkler_Id</b></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>Schedule_Id</b></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>Starttime</b></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>Stoptime</b></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>Monday</b></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>Tuesday</b></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>Wednesday</b></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>Thursday</b></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>Friday</b></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>Saturday</b></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>Sunday</b></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 

    $sql = "SELECT daystime.*, Sprinkler_ID FROM daystime, scheduler WHERE daystime.id = scheduler.DaysTime_ID ORDER BY Sprinkler_ID, daystime.id";
    $results=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {
    $id = $row['id']; 
    echo "<tr>";
     if( in_array(  $row['Sprinkler_ID'], $sprinkleIds ) {
          $text = 'Yes';
        } else {
          $text = 'No';
        }
        echo "<td valign='top'>" . $text . "</td>";  
    echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['id']) . "</td>";  
    echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['starttime']) . "</td>";  
    echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['stoptime']) . "</td>";  
    echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['mon']) . "</td>";  
    echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['tue']) . "</td>";  
    echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['wed']) . "</td>";  
    echo "<td valign=

'top'>" . nl2br( $row['thu']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['fri']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['sat']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['sun']) . "</td>";  
echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 

?>
```

Comment: can you please add this code to my code so I understand well. thanks

Comment: do i need to repeat this code 8 times for each Sprkr number??

Comment: No its in loop no need to repeat

Comment: yes but u did not create 8 columns for each sprinkler so how is this supposed to work as if I understand the code it will still print in one column. right??

Comment: @PrerakDiwan "while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results))" loops through all the rows retrieved from the database, which is stored in the "$results" variable

Comment: @lampdev I updated the images so u understand what I require. Thanks